# How To Back Up a Database from My Web Hosting Server to My Computer

Tags: sql-server, web

i wana back up my database from my web hosting to my computer but i face [this](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting033.htm) errror .

i google it but none of the solution work for me . 
i only have the servername, username , password and initial catalog.
is any thing else needed to make a back up ?

any idea ?

Regards,

Comment: without details like how you try to do the backup and the actual error message it will be hard to help.

Comment: Where are you trying to backup to? The backup location needs to be a path on the server not your local machine.

Comment: what do you mean by how to back up ?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server performs backups to the local drive. You can't tell it to backup the database to your machine over internet. What you need to do is to backup the database  on the hosting service and then download it to your machine. In order to perform this you need to contact help desk of your hosting, so that they could give you adequate details how to do this. Most likely this will be one of the two:

1) They will tell you what local path to use to save your backup. If the database instance is located on the same box as the file system that hosts your files they will be able to tell you what path to specify so that the backup ends up in "your" hosting folder.

2) They will tell you to use their tool (something like web control panel) that is hosting specific to obtain the backup of your database.

They also might suggest an alternate solution. Ask them they are in the best position to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Many web hosts won't give you a means of using the native SQL backup functionality directly within their environment. Working within the constraints of having nothing more than remote user access with (I assume) DBO rights, one thing you might try is using [Red Gate's SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to sync the remote machine to a local instance of the database. Of course you could also script it yourself with a lot more time.

BTW, you haven't mentioned data size, but this is the sort of thing that can get quite painful with large volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

This tool allows you to backup your sql databases to an sql file which you can save on your local machine.

Comment: phpMyAdmin does not work with SQL Server, only with MySql and also requires php which is unlikely to be present on the windows based hosting.